# Difference between truncation, transaction and deletion database strategies

Tags: ruby, database, testing, rspec

What is the difference between truncation, transaction and deletion database strategies when using Rspec? I can't find any resources explaining this. I read the Database Cleaner readme but it doesn't explain what each of these do.

Why do we have to use truncation strategy for Capybara? Do I have to clean up my database when testing or can I disable it. I dont understand why I should clean up my database after each test case, wouldn't it just slow down testing?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The database cleaning strategies refer to database terminology. I.e. those terms come from the (SQL) database world, so people generally familiar with database terminology will know what they mean.

The examples below refer to SQL definitions. `DatabaseCleaner` however supports other non-SQL types of databases too, but generally the definitions will be the same or similar.

**Deletion**

This means the database tables are cleaned using the SQL `DELETE FROM` statement. This is usually [slower than truncation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/delete-vs-truncate), but [may have other advantages instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900557/823617).

**Truncation**

This means the database tables are cleaned using the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement. This will simply empty the table immediately, without deleting the table structure itself or deleting records individually.

**Transaction**

This means using `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statements coupled with `ROLLBACK` to roll back a sequence of previous database operations. Think of it as an "undo button" for databases. I would think this is the most frequently used cleaning method, and probably the fastest since changes need not be directly committed to the DB.

Example discussion: [Rspec, Cucumber: best speed database clean strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378568/rspec-cucumber-best-speed-database-clean-strategy)

**Reason for truncation strategy with Capybara**

The best explanation was found in the [Capybara docs themselves](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara):

```
# Transactional fixtures do not work with Selenium tests, because Capybara
# uses a separate server thread, which the transactions would be hidden
# from. We hence use DatabaseCleaner to truncate our test database.
```

**Cleaning requirements**

You do not necessarily have to clean your database after each test case. However you need to be aware of side effects this could have. I.e. if you create, modify, or delete some records in one step, will the other steps be affected by this?

Normally RSpec runs with transactional fixtures turned on, so you will never notice this when running RSpec - it will simply keep the database automatically clean for you:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-10/docs/transactions

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. That really explains a lot. The link to rspec-rails docs is also extremely useful. I greatly appreciate you're help :)

Comment: This is not quite true. The [deletion strategy](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/blob/master/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/deletion.rb) is actually supposed to be faster than truncation because it executes `DELETE FROM table` instead of `TRUNCATE TABLE table` -- so it removes all the records without doing stuff like resetting sequences.